# If $\subseteq$ is defined set-theoretically, it doesn't exist

Tags: set-theory

I came across the following statement:

> If the subset relation $\subseteq $ is defined as a set in ZFC, then it doesn't exist because $\mathrm{dom(}R\mathrm{)}$ is guaranteed to exist for any relation $R$, and $\mathrm{dom(\subseteq)}$ is $V$, which doesn't exist.

I understand everything except "$\mathrm{dom(\subseteq)}$ is $V$". The domain of $\subseteq$ is the set of all $A$'s such that $A\subseteq B$, but since we are defining $\subseteq$ set-theoretically, $A$ is not *any* set, it is *any set in ZFC*, so I don't understand how this domain equals $V$.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The distinction you make between *any set* and *any set in ZFC* doesn't seem to have any sense to me (I would say they mean the same thing). Could you explain how those two differ?

Comment: @Adayah, now I see where my mistake was: ZFC proves the existence of any set in $V$, but not the existence of $V$ itself... All the answers, including yours, assume I know this (which I do, but did not notice and take into account here). Your comment answers my question, so if you want you can make it into a proper answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad to help, but I still don't understand what your mistake was, so I don't really know what I should put in the answer. :p Also, now the statement *ZFC proves the existence of any set in $V$* doesn't make sense to me, but it's probably because I'm taking it literally.

Comment: @Adayah, I thought that "all of the objects ZFC can talk about" and "everything in $V$" were different things, and they aren't. Do you understand what my mistake was now?

Comment: @Adayah please leave a reply confirming I'm not making another mistake :)

Comment: Let's say I'm beginning to understand. What did you think the difference was?

Comment: "ZFC proves the existence of any set in $V$." This statement, in my reckoning, both makes sense and is wrong.  On the other hand, the idea of ZFC proving or not proving "the existence of $V$" makes very little sense, though I gather what you're probably going for there is "ZFC proves $V$ is not a set". One issue here is that the things ZFC *actually* proves are sentences in the formal language of set theory, but we generally instead communicate 'ideas' ZFC proves in natural language, and it's not always obvious how to match up ideas with their formalizations unless we are specific.

Comment: And also people can reasonably disagree whether a formalization is an adequate expression of a given idea, or whether a idea is a fair informal description of a given formal sentence or sentence scheme. Just as people can disagree about whether an idea is precise enough to take seriously mathematically.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen regarding your first comment: I understand all of the points you raise, I was just being somewhat sloppy with my language. Still, it is true that for any set $S$ in $V$, ZFC proves "$\exists x (x=S)$, but does not prove "$\exists x (x=V)$.

Comment: @alex811 But this still doesn't make a lot of sense because it's unclear what the expressions $x=S$ and $x=V$ mean. "$x=V$" is presumably shorthand for $\forall y(y\in x \leftrightarrow y=y)$ in which case, yes ZFC does not prove $\exists x (x=V)$ and even proves its negation. On the other hand, if we try to treat "$x=S$" on the same footing, it is just wrong. Say $S$ is the least inaccessible cardinal and we give its definition as the property $\phi(x),$ then $ZFC$ can't prove $\exists x \phi(x).$ And we can't even express this for sets in $V$ that aren't definable.

Comment: @alex811 On the other hand, ZFC can prove the trivial statement $\forall y\exists x(x=y),$ but that inverts "ZFC proves" and the universal quantifier and doesn't put things on the same footing as we did for $x=V$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen aren't "all of the objects in $V$" and "all of the objects that exist in ZFC" the same thing?

Comment: @alex811 “exist in ZFC” is an ambiguous phrase. ZFC proves things. $V$ is a domain of discourse for the semantics of ZFC. So we interpret the quantifiers as ranging over $V$ and in that sense $V$ is “everything”. But that doesn’t mean that for a given set in $V,$ ZFC can prove its existence (i.e. prove it is in $V$) in the same sense as it proves the existence of the empty set or the natural numbers.

Comment: @alex811 should have been more precise and said “the semantics of ZFC’s *language*”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $x\subseteq x$ holds for every $x$. So, if you were write down the definition of $\operatorname{dom}({\subseteq})$ you'd get $\{x:(\exists y)(x\subseteq y)\}$, which is a subclass of $V$, but by the first sentence $V$ is part of $\operatorname{dom}({\subseteq})$.

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is the common name for the collection of all sets (which doesn't exist as a set, as implied by the [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox), therefore we often refer to it as the *class of all sets*). As you probably know,

$$\operatorname{dom} R = \{ x : (\exists y) \, (x, y) \in R \}. $$

Since for each set $A$ there is a set $B$ (for instance, $B = A$) such that $A \subseteq B$, we have that if $\subseteq$ were a set, then $\operatorname{dom} \subseteq$ would be the set of all sets $V$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $V$ is being used, presumably, to stand for the "universe" of all sets, which is a class but is not a set. To say that "dom($\subseteq$) is $V$" simply means that in the sentence $A \subseteq B$, you may replace $A$ by any set, i.e. any element of $V$, and you may replace $B$ by any set, and  having made those replacements the sentence will then have a truth value.

Comment: I understand all this, but defining $\subseteq$ set-theoretically restricts $A$ to be a set in ZFC, not a set in $V$.

Comment: @alex No, that really makes no sense. It is like claiming that $-3$ is not the additive inverse of 3 in the group $\mathbb Z$ but rather in the theory of groups. You are mixing the theory the discussion takes place in,  in this case ZFC, with the objects involved in the discussion, in this case the full set-theoretic universe $V$.

Comment: I think the OP quite clearly indicates we are in the context of the axiomatic set theory. In that context $\operatorname{dom}$ has a strict definition and it is not the (unstrict) definition you are using.